# Processing too many calls to popMatrix

Tags: java, opengl, processing

I'm developing a Processing view (with v2.2.1 that still extends Applet).
I use some pushMatrix()/popMatrix() to do transformations and to represent composite objects (I'm aware of the 32 depth matrix stack limit and relatively sure I don't reach that depth in composition and/or successive transformations or dont pair push and pops properly).

So far I didn't have any unexpected issue, but after introducing yet another component(not the first text enabled component at all), I'm starting to occasionally get errors like these:

The font size is too large to be properly displayed with OpenGL

> Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Image width and height cannot be larger than 0 with this graphics
>   card.     at processing.opengl.Texture.setSize(Texture.java:1148)     at
>   processing.opengl.Texture.init(Texture.java:213)  at
>   processing.opengl.Texture.(Texture.java:160)    at
>   processing.opengl.FontTexture.addTexture(FontTexture.java:134)    at
>   processing.opengl.FontTexture.initTexture(FontTexture.java:103)   at
>   processing.opengl.FontTexture.(FontTexture.java:71)     at
>   processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL.textLineImpl(PGraphicsOpenGL.java:3602)
>     at processing.core.PGraphics.textLineAlignImpl(PGraphics.java:4659)
>     at processing.core.PGraphics.text(PGraphics.java:4356)  at
>   processing.core.PGraphics.text(PGraphics.java:4307)   at
>   processing.core.PApplet.text(PApplet.java:13183)  at
>   ygg.desktop.vm.extVM.MetadataProcessingVM.render(MetadataProcessingVM.java:81)
>     at
>   ygg.desktop.vm.extVM.MetadataProcessingVM.render(MetadataProcessingVM.java:88)
>     at ygg.desktop.vm.groups.TreeLayout.render(TreeLayout.java:43)  at
>   ygg.desktop.vm.groups.RenderArea.render(RenderArea.java:167)  at
>   ygg.desktop.view.MainView.draw(MainView.java:179)     at
>   processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2386)     at
>   processing.core.PGraphicsJava2D.requestDraw(PGraphicsJava2D.java:240)
>     at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2256)   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

which refers to (note that I get it both on first and second text on different runs) *father is the PApplet instance

```
          father.pushMatrix();
          father.translate(posX, posY+8);

          father.rotate(-father.HALF_PI);

          father.fill(father.color(30,30,30));
          father.textAlign(father.CENTER);
          father.textSize(16);
          **father.text(md.getId()!=null?md.getId():"NONE",-(finalY-posY)/2,width/2);**
          father.fill(father.color(220,220,50));
          father.textSize(12);
          **father.text(md.getId()!=null?md.getId():"NONE",-(finalY-posY)/2,width/2);**

          father.popMatrix();
```

or

> Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: Too
>   many calls to popMatrix(), and not enough to pushMatrix().    at
>   processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL.popMatrix(PGraphicsOpenGL.java:3811)
>     at processing.core.PApplet.popMatrix(PApplet.java:13322)    at
>   ygg.desktop.vm.extVM.MetadataProcessingVM.render(MetadataProcessingVM.java:72)
>     at ygg.desktop.vm.groups.TreeLayout.render(TreeLayout.java:43)  at
>   ygg.desktop.vm.groups.TreeLayout.render(TreeLayout.java:46)   at
>   ygg.desktop.vm.groups.TreeLayout.render(TreeLayout.java:46)   at
>   ygg.desktop.vm.groups.RenderArea.render(RenderArea.java:167)  at
>   ygg.desktop.view.MainView.draw(MainView.java:180)     at
>   processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2386)     at
>   processing.core.PGraphicsJava2D.requestDraw(PGraphicsJava2D.java:240)
>     at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2256)   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

on

```
          father.pushMatrix();
          father.translate(posX, posY+8);
          father.rotate(-father.HALF_PI);
          father.fill(father.color(30,30,30));
          father.textAlign(father.CENTER);
          father.textSize(16);

          father.text(md.getId()!=null?md.getId():"NONE",-(finalY-posY)/2,width/2);
          father.fill(father.color(220,220,50));
          father.textSize(12);
          father.text(md.getId()!=null?md.getId():"NONE",-(finalY-posY)/2,width/2);      
          **father.popMatrix();**
    }
```

I am no expert in OpenGl and/or Processing at all, so I was wondering how can successive executions (with no previous jvm left open) lead to different outcomes without any random element in my code (apparently if the application doesnt crash immediately it keeps working no matter how many objects I create), also I don't understand how can I get that exception on popMatrix right after a push given that all the calls are in the draw cycle and of course no thread (that I'm aware) there.

Before proceeding I would like to know what am I getting so wrong (if it as already transpired) and what could I do to achieve stability at each run, also I would like to know if multiple instances of PApplet clients will necessarly confict with each others.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to pin point all the errors without the full code listing.

From what you posted it looks like you have unpaired pushMatrix()/popMatrix() calls. For each pushMatrix() operation you will need a popMatrix() when you're done doing local coordinate system transformations.

Be sure to read the [2D Transformations Processing tutorial](https://processing.org/tutorials/transform2d/) for more details.